# highcharts conditional show / hide for multiple series

Tags: javascript, highcharts, react-highcharts

I have a chart that display the sales for Phone, Laptops and Printers and I can toggle any option on/off. I also have another toggle button "Without Taxes" that will display for each option (phone, laptops, printer) some new series.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWmnI.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Flvjn.png)

The big problem is that if I disable laptops & printer the "without taxes" toggle button will display all the lines not only the "phone without takes "
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZwny.png)

My implementations looks like this:

```
"series": [ 
            {
                "name": "Phones",
                "id": "phonesId",
                "template": "line",
                "data": [
                    ....
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Laptops",
                "id": "laptopId",
                "template": "line",
                "data": [
                    ....
                ]
            }
            {
                "name": "Printers",
                "id": "printersId",
                "template": "line",
                "data": [
                    ....
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Without Taxes",
                "id":"noTaxesId",
                "template": "line-thin",
                "data": [],
            },
            {
                "name": "Phones No Taxes",
                "linkedTo":"noTaxesId",
                "template": "line-thin",
                "data": [
                    ....
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Laptops No Taxes",
                "linkedTo":"noTaxesId",
                "template": "line-thin",
                "data": [
                    ....
                ]
            }
            {
                "name": "Printers No Taxes",
                "linkedTo":"noTaxesId",
                "template": "line-thin",
                "data": [
                    ....
                ]
            }
]
```

So I'm using an empty serie with id: "noTaxesId" and then I use "linkedTo":"noTaxesId" for the next 3 series.

Somehow I want to make the "Without taxes" toggle button to show only for the options that are active not for all of them all the time

Comment: Hi @Amold78, Could you show your current implementation in some online code editor? You can start from: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bmofyasd/

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek! Thanks for your interest! I have solved by handeling the click events in the plotOptions legendItemClick from highcharts!